# Get return value from running %run magics

Tags: ipython

My python script return a value(double type) and I run my script using %run magics, 
for example: %run myScript.py

I would like to know I can I get the return value(double type) from running %run magics?

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
%run myScript.py
```

any objects created while runing the script will be left in the current Ipython namespace.

So if `myScript` contains:

```
def foo(x):
    return x*2
if __name__=='__main__':
    y = foo(12.34)
```

Both `foo` and `y` will be available to you after the `run`.

Look at `%run?` for more options.